# Cast Time to String issue- snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I'm casting a time datatype column to a string I'm getting a different value.

For example :

```sql
SELECT "time_column" 
FROM "products"
```

**returns 15:34:21**

```sql
SELECT  cast( "time_column"  as STRING )
FROM  "products"
```

**returns  13:34:21**

Any idea why this happens and how to correctly convert from time to string?

Also tried `to_varchar("time_column", 'HH24:MI:SS')` but getting the same result.

Comment: Where do you live -- this looks like the difference between GMT and your local time zone.

Comment: yes. it's related to time zones. im on UTC+2 and that's why i'm getting a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting a different time value when you cast the "time_column" to a string is that the time zone of the session you're using in Snowflake is different from the time zone used to store the time values in the "time_column".

To get the correct time value in string format, you can use the TIME_FORMAT() function in Snowflake. This function converts the time value to a specified format without any time zone conversion.

For example, if you want to convert the "time_column" values to string format in the format 'HH24:MI:SS', you can use the following SQL query:
`SELECT TIME_FORMAT("time_column", 'HH24:MI:SS')  FROM "products";`

This should return the "time_column" values in the 'HH24:MI:SS' format, without any time zone conversion.

Comment: Thanks! and what if I don't know the format? I want it to use the same format it was saved in

Comment: @Lee -- it was not saved in a string format, timestamps are saved as a number, you have to convert them to a string to display them.